# Disabled text-area in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, tags, disable

I'm trying to put the disabled attribute in  in angularJS It doesn't work at all, I've already tried ng-disabled="true", via script and it doesn't work. If I change it to  it works normal, but I need to do it with the . Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You need to show some code, the domain is too vast otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a textarea like this

```
<textarea type="text" ng-model="someModel" ng-readonly="disablingAttribute"></textarea>
```

And inside your controller if you have

```
$scope.disablingAttribute = true;
```

It will functionally disable your textarea.
For more information on this, read about [ng-readonly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) directive